# How linux terminate processes

Tags: linux, process, linux-kernel, pthreads, sigkill

I want know some details about process termination. Thanks.
Does process have cancellation points like pthread? 
If yes, what are they? Does SIGKILL take those cancellation points into account?
Does signal change process states to run signal handler? If yes, does it mean a process will never terminate itself when it never get cpu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does process have cancellation points like pthread?

No.

> Does SIGKILL take those cancellation points into account?

No, because there are none.  When a `SIGKILL` is delivered to a process, it dies.  If it is waiting on completion of any system calls then those waits are interrupted.  No thread makes any further computational progress or performs any cleanup, but on-termination cleanup performed by the OS (closing open files, releasing memory, ...) generally still happens.  `SIGKILL` cannot be caught, blocked, or ignored.

Compare `SIGTERM`, which is a bit gentler.  When a process receives a `SIGTERM`, which may be deferred by blocking it or prevented by ignoring it, the result depends on whether a signal handler is registered for it.  If so, then any system call being executed by the thread chosen to receive the signal is interrupted, and the signal handler is called.  Additional effects are program-specific.  If no handler is registered then the program skips to performing a clean(-ish) termination, including calling registered exit handlers before actually terminating.

> Does signal change process states to run signal handler?

I'm not sure what you mean by that, but no signal handlers are invoked in the `SIGKILL` case.  More broadly, however, when signal handlers do run, such as may happen in the `SIGTERM` case, they are asynchronous with respect to the execution of the thread in which they run.

> If yes, does it mean a process will never terminate itself when it never get cpu.

Terminating a process by delivering a `SIGKILL` to it does not require any cooperation from the process.  All significant operations involved are performed by the kernel, and since it is in charge of scheduling execution resources, you cannot easily deny the kernel whatever CPU time it wants.

Delivering a `SIGTERM` to a process, on the other hand, is not always successful in making it terminate.  The process can block or ignore the signal, or handle it without terminating.  Even if it does none of those things, its exit handlers (if any) will run before it terminates, and these can delay its actual termination indefinitely.  In principle, you can prevent the termination from completing by preventing the process from being scheduled any CPU time.

Comment: Thanks very much. I have read some kernel code, it seems that SIGKILL handler is also executed by the target process( the process can do nothing about the handler, of course), so I guess there must be some situations SIGKILL can't work. For the question "Does signal change process states to run signal handler", I mean OS must change the target process state to TASK_RUNNING if it's hung-up or blocked, because all signal handlers must be executed by the target process. Do I make something wrong?

Comment: @Alan, the point of `SIGKILL` is that there is no situation in which it doesn't work.  You seem to be focusing on implementation details, but these are secondary.  If `SIGKILL` ever failed to kill a process to which it was delivered then that would characterize an operating system bug.

Answer (score 1):

In Linux, when a process is killed, a “terminating signal” is delivered to the process. Although there are many different types of signals, we mostly deal with the “SIGTERM” and “SIGKILL” signals. They have a numeric value of 15 and 9 respectively.

Default, all the process killing commands use “SIGTERM”, which allows the program to run some code before it exits, thus allowing it to terminate “gracefully”.

If you want to terminate the process forcibly, you can use “SIGKILL” instead.